# Apache SOLR - full import fetches only like half of the records

Tags: solr

I'm using the JdbcDataSource to fetch records from a view in my MySQL database.

When running the view in phpMyadmin issuing a count(*) command, I get 97670 records.

But when running a full import in SOLR, only 56428 records are fetched and indexed. I don't get any errors, everything seems to be ok on SOLR (I did set batchSize to -1).

Any explanations for this behaviour?

Comment: Usually it's caused by duplicate entries your unique id field, resulting in later documents overwriting the previously indexed ones.

Comment: Thanks - I checked the UIDs of the view and they are indeed unique. Wouldn't SOLR tell me if there were duplicate entries (like, saying skipped = n)?

Comment: No, the entry wasn't skipped - it was indexed; it just overwrote the previous entry (skipped is entries being skipped by DIH). Find the entries that hasn't been added to the database and check what their values are in the unique fields, or if there are other required fields that have missing values (they would normally be shown in the log, but DIH might be special)

Comment: Thanks again! I did a query for with some of the missing entries' IDs - and didn't get any results back. If they'd be overwritten, I should get a result but with a different content than I'd expect? So I guess they really aren't indexed at all.

Comment: That depends - start by checking the rows in the database and compare them to those that have been indexed. You might have other fields that are defined as unique or required than the single unique id field.

Comment: Just from a quick look - the only field that's defined as unique is the ID-field (thanks again for your efforts!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have checked solr logs and no errors are logged there In this case you can try executing the commit command on your solr collection as sometimes the documents are buffered in memory and we can push them to the disk by commiting them

Comment: I feel soooo stupid right now. I didn't look at the logs, just saw the green indicator on the import screen. There WAS an error and I was able to fix it (date field with zero values). Thanks a ton for the nudge!